# Number of sequences with n digits, even number of 1's (Continued question)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, recurrence-relations

Some guy asked a very interesting [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421946/number-of-sequences-with-n-digits-even-number-of-1s) here before. He was trying to figure out a formula to calculate $a_n$ number of sequences with n digits from $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and an even number of 1's. Which turns out to be: $$\frac{4^n+2^n}{2}$$However, the question was only answered properly through a generating function method, which, whilst I love the idea of it, is a tad bit too complex for me.

How does one create a recurrence relation for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit 1

To visualise what I'm looking for:

$a_0 = |\{\}| = 0$

$a_1 = |\{2,3,4\}| = 3$

$a_2 = |\{11,22,33,24,32,33,34,42,43,44\}| = 10$

$a_3 = 36$

I don't suppose one would be able to notice a pattern from this? Or deduct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create $n+1$ digits number just by 'adding' one number as the left-most digit to $n$ digits number. (For example, you can create $1312$ by adding $1$ as the left most digit to $312$.)

Case 1 : If the number of $1$'s is odd in a $n$ digits number, then you need to add $1$ as the left most digit of a new $n+1$ digits number. So, in this case, you have
$$(4^n-c_n)\cdot 1\ \ \text{(cases)}.$$

Case 2 : If the number of $1$'s is even in a $n$ digits number, then you need to add $2,3,\text{or}\ 4$ as the left most digit of a new $n+1$ digits number. So, in this case, you have
$$c_n\cdot 3\ \ \text{(cases)}.$$

Hence, you'll have
$$c_{n+1}=(4^n-c_n)\cdot 1+c_n\cdot 3.$$

Comment: Very insightful. I have one question though. Is there any better way to understand the $4^n-c_n$ part? I'm very puzzled by that.

Comment: @XMLParsing: $4^n$ represents the number of the $n$ digits numbers which can be represented by $1,2,3,4$. So, $4^n-c_n$ represents the number of the $n$ digits numbers which have **odd** number of $1$'s.